# Images-Updates with OpenCV and Python for ROS-Maps

Tags: python, image, opencv, dictionary, ros

Good morning everone, we have a autonomus Robot with a Lidar. We use ROS as a framework for mapping and navigation.
A task that I'm right now dealing with is, the updates of the maps, that we are providing our robot.
The idea is to add new obstacles and remove those, that are not longer there. Everytime a new map (.pgm-file) is being created and should be compared with the old one. I'm trying to find a way to update the map even if not the whole area was scanned. The problem is that if the robot happend to be only in a part of the whole area, it doesn't know what's there and the new map has a big unknown zone that must not be on the new map. I thought maybe about some loop that picks the differences between two maps but skips the pixels with the value of 'gray=unknown' (I think its a value of 205).
I thank you very much in advance.

[Karte_ROS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM4oR.jpg)

Comment: You should add some example images.

Comment: Is it a 2D lidar or 3D lidar?

Comment: It's a 3D lidar but we use only one layer, so the map is 2D first

Comment: As far as I understand, your problem is to compare the new image with the map to find where to update. If that is the case, two raw examples would be more helpful than a processed result. Otherwise, if the image registration is done, something like `newImg.copyTo(map, ~(newImg == 205))` may work.